# How to filter items using an input field and a dropdown in PowerApps?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I have connected my Excel table to a gallery control in PowerApps. I have a dropdown box to select values for the 'Manager' column and an input field to type in the name of the employee. I tried doing-

```
Filter(Table1,StartsWith(Name,empSearchbox.Text) && (Manager = dropdownManager.Selected.Value ||dropdownManager.Selected.Value=Blank()))
```

This gives me errors-

```
    Issue 
        Incompatible types for comparison. These types can't be compared: Text, Error.
        We can't evaluate your formula because the values being compared in the formula aren't the same type.
```

Second error:

```
        Name isn't valid. This identifier isn't recognized. 
        This error appears most commonly when a formula refers to something that no longer exists (for example, a control that you've deleted). 
        Location No
```

The first part in the Filter function works alone.
Edit: The = and .Value are underlined in red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your dropdownManager field has a blank value as initial/unselected value, try:

```
Filter(
  Table1,
  StartsWith(
    Name,
    empSearchbox.Text
  ) && ( Manager = dropdownManager.Selected.Result || isBlank( dropdownManager.Selected.Result)
  )
)
```

This will get you started ;-)

Comment: The dropdown has values from the Manager column. Name and Manager are two different columns.

Comment: C'mon, some flexibilty would be nice ;-)
Edited the code to manager.

Comment: I tried the above and the entire isBlank part is underlined in red now.

Comment: Image of your error?

Comment: I see, i forgot one ) at the end

Comment: There are more than one error messages actually. Just a minute.

Comment: Unexpected characters. The formula contains 'ParenClose' where tot is expected. This error occurs it for example, a formula contains '{Val© 7}' instead of {Val: 7y. When you set a variable, the syntax requires a colon instead of an "at" symbol.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242364/discussion-between-iona-varga-and-pete).